# Find the value of $s$ for which the matrix is positive definite

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-definite

I am given the following Matrix

$$
A=        \begin{pmatrix}
        s & -4 & -4 \\
        -4 & s & -4 \\
        -4 & -4 & s \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

and asked to find $s$ such that $A$ is positive definite. In finding it, I simply set the determinant to $0$ and solved for $s$, and in doing so, I got $0 = s^2-4s-32$ which solves to $s=-4,8$. I'm not sure whether this is the correct process though, and if I use either value for $s$ I have at least one $0$ for each eigenvalue of $A$. Am I on the right track? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why set the determinant to zero? 

I may be mistaken, cause I don't remember this topic very well but wasn't a matrix positive definite iff the three determinants (of the full 3x3, of the left-top 2x2 matrix and of the left-top 1x1 matrix) were all positive? This would give you three inequalities with $s$ to work with.

Comment: @Iwanttomakegames is correct.  Since $A$ is symmetric, Sylvester's Criterion tells you that $A$ is positive-definite if and only if its three principal minors (the determinants of the three submatrices that he mentioned) are all positive.  So you need $s>0$ as well as $s^{2}-16>0$ and $0<s(s^{2}-16)+4(-4s-16)-4(16+4s)=s(s^{2}-16)-128-32s=s^{3}-48s-128$.  That is, you need $s>4$ which also makes the expression $s^{3}-48s-128>0$.  My advice is to graph the cubic function $f(x)=x^{3}-48x-128$, and examine the range of this function over the restricted domain $x>4$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The matrix $A$ will be positive definite if and only if all its eigenvalues are positive. You have

$$ A = \left( \begin{matrix} s & -4 & -4 \\ -4 & s & -4 \\ -4 & -4 & s \end{matrix} \right) = \left( \begin{matrix} -4 & -4 & -4 \\ -4 & -4 & -4 \\ -4 & -4 & -4 \end{matrix} \right) + \left( \begin{matrix} s + 4 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & s + 4 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & s + 4 \end{matrix} \right) = B + (s+4)I. $$

The eigenvalues of $B$ are $0$ (with multiplicity $2$) and $-12$ (with multiplicity $1$) and so the eigenvalues of $A$ are $s + 4$ (with multiplicity $2$) and $s - 8$ (with multiplicity $1$). Thus, $A$ will be positive definite if and only if $s + 4 > 0$ and $s - 8 > 0$ - that is, if and only if $s > 8$.

---

In the answer, we used the observation that if $B$ is a diagonalizable matrix with eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n$ and $p(X) = a_nX^n + \ldots + a_0$ is a polynomial, then $p(B)$ (which is also diagonalizable) has eigenvalues $p(\lambda_1), \ldots, p(\lambda_n)$. This is easily proved by checking that if $v_i$ is an eigenvector of $B$ with $Bv_i = \lambda_i v_i$ then it is also an eigenvector of $p(B)$ and $p(B)v_i = p(\lambda_i) v_i$. In our case, $p(X) = X + (s + 4)$.

Comment: +1: The reason, I beat you, is that I used the \begin{pmatrix}-tag only once and not thrice :)

Comment: Another possible reason is that I used \left( \begin{matrix} instead of \begin{pmatrix}. Thank you for teaching me something new!

Comment: Ah, I completely missed that you could break the matrix up like that when I looked at the problem. Thanks for the awesome answers! However, could you please explain why the eigenvalues of A are s+4 and s-8? I can't seem to follow where this conclusion comes from in both of the answers given for this question. Thanks!

Comment: I've added an explanation.

Comment: Thanks levap...but isn't B not diagonizable (as in, I can't write it as A=X*diag*X^-1)? Also, what I really don't understand is you got s-8 from. Could you explain that process for me? I appreciate it.

Comment: The matrix $B$ is symmetric and so is surely diagonalizable. You can also see this by explicitly calculating the eigenspaces - the eigenspace of $0$ is $\{ (x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4)^T \, | \, x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 0\}$ and the eigenspace of $1$ is $\mathrm{span} \{ (1,1,1,1)^T \}$. Since the eigenvalues of $B$ are $0,0,-12$, the eigenvalues of $A = p(B)$ are $p(0), p(0), p(-12)$ which is $s+4, s+4, s-8$.

Comment: I understand what you have all meant now! I kind of understand the first comment you made explaining why the technique works...but could you tell me why I can use the eigenvalues of B for A (as in how you separated $A=B+(s+4)I$? I'm in a linear algebra class and my professor is no good, and this is a technique I haven't seen yet, so I really want to familiarize myself with it and understand it fully. Thanks once again for the help!

Comment: Let me demonstrate this for $A = B + (s+4)I$. If $v$ is an eigenvector of $B$ associated with eigenvalue $\lambda$, we have $Bv = \lambda v$. Then $Av = (B + (s+4)I)v = Bv + (s+4)v = \lambda v + (s+4) v = (\lambda + s + 4) v$ which shows that $\lambda + s + 4 = p(\lambda)$ is an eigenvalue of $A$. This works more generally for any polynomial expression in $B$.

Comment: Thank you for all the help levap! I think that completely clarifies the concept for me. I appreciate all the support you gave me in this question :)

P.S: You get best answer props

Answer (score 4):

You could also approach it like this: A symmetric matrix is postive definite iff all eigenvalues are positive.

Take $s=-4$ and we have a rank $1$-matrix $A = \begin{pmatrix}-4&-4&-4\\-4&-4&-4\\-4&-4&-4\end{pmatrix}$. Such a matrix has two different eigenvalues: $0$ and the trace, which is $-12$.

For arbitrary $s$ our matrix is of the form $(s+4)\operatorname{Id}+A$, hence the eigenvalues are $s+4$ and $s+4-12=s-8$. This shows that the matrix is positive definite iff $s > 8$.